Non-trivial solutions to homogenous system
If I was given two vectors (both $4 \times 1$) and told that they are non-trivial solutions to a homogenous system $Ax=0$, can I obtain a third vector in the solution set? Would this be enough information? Could I just multiply one of the vectors by a scalar?

The solutions to a homogeneous linear system form a linear space. In particular, if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are solutions, then $c_1x_1 + c_2x_2$ is a solution for any scalars $c_1$, $c_2$.

I'll expand on David Gao's comment and place it as an answer.
Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Recall that the null space of $A$, which I denote $N(A)$ (some books, like Lay, use $\operatorname{Nul} A$) is the collection of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $Ax = 0.$ This is also called the kernel of A, denoted $\operatorname{Ker} A.$
It's easy to see that $N(A)$ is indeed a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For your question specifically, if we have nonzero $u, v \in N(A)$, then certainly any linear combination is in $N(A)$. Why? Well, for $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{align*}
A(\lambda u + \mu v) &= A(\lambda u) + A(\mu v) \\
&= \lambda Au + \mu Av \\
&= 0 + 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
just by using the properties of matrix multiplication. So, knowing any two non-trivial solutions can net you a third (or fourth, or fifth, or...)!

It should be noted that this answer does depend on doing linear algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Over finite fields, there can be solutions sets that are larger than singletons but not infinite, since linear subspaces of vector spaces over finite fields can have finitely many elements. Since this question is rather elementary, it's probably safe to assume the field is $\mathbb{R}$ as you did, but I wanted to point it out since I just saw a finite field linear algebra question a few moments ago.

@walkar Very nice point to add - as I don't know much about finite fields, I always consider the parent field of a vector space $\mathbb{F}$ to be the real or complex numbers.

I do characteristic $p$ methods, so finite fields are always lurking around. Infinitude of an underlying field is also very important in commutative algebra, so I think about these issues frequently.
